# How to handle in JS an error message thrown by a commandButton's action

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

In a JSF 2.1 wep app, I have a column of a dataTable that contains a commandButton. The action triggered by the commandButton may throw an error. **I want to open a dialog in case no errors are thrown, or a box containing the error message in the other case**.

**JSF**

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="foo" value="#{myBean.foos}" >
        <p:column>#{foo.id}</p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton title="Action" action="#{myBean.action()}" onComplete="handleResult(xhr, status, args)" >
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{foo}" target="#{myBean.selectedFoo}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function handleRequest(xhr, status, args) {
    if (!args.success) {
        displayBox(args.errorMsg);
    } else {
        displayDialog();
    }
}
```

**MyBean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {
    private List<Foo> foos;
    private Foo selectedFoo;

    public void action() {
        try {
            // business logic
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            RequestContext rContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            rContext.addCallbackParam("success", false);
            rContext.addCallbackParam("errorMsg", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The only solution I can think of is using PrimeFaces' `RequestContext.callBackParam()` and writing a JS function that reads it and decides what to open.

Is there a smoother way? I'd consider to leverage the concept of validation, if possible, but I can't find an example of how to intercept the error in JS.

Comment: Don't think in javascript, just make it via Ajax and let the server use JSF functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way is to just add a global faces message (thus, with `null` client ID).

```
public void action() {
    try {
        // business logic
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        context.validationFailed();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
            FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, ex.getMessage(), null));
    }
}
```

*(calling `FacesContext#validationFailed()` will cause `#{facesContext.validationFailed}` in EL to evaluate `true`; this is normally set in case of `ValidatorException`)*

Then, to display a box for global message only, just use `<p:messages globalOnly="true">`.

```
<p:messages globalOnly="true" autoUpdate="true" />
```

And to display a dialog on successful outcome, let it render when a [successful](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29) [postback](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback%28%29) is performed:

```
<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
    <p:dialog visible="true" rendered="#{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.validationFailed}">
        A successful postback is performed!
    </p:dialog>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Replace if necessary `autoUpdate="true"` of one or the both components by `update="messagesId dialogPanelId"` so that it's only triggered when the particular button is pressed.

Comment: Superb answer as usual. Thanks!